# How do I verify an asymmetrically signed JWT in dotnet core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, rsa

I have found examples of asymmetric signing in .NET FW and examples of symmetric signing in .NET Core, but I cannot figure out how to asymmetrically verify a JWT in .NET Core.  Given a URL to a JWK Set or given a public key, how can I verify a token in .NET Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up implementing the [OpenID Connect Discovery](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) spec, which allows you to publish the token endpoint and keyset endpoint in a standard format.  Then I could use the `AddJwtBearer()` `AuthenticationBuilder` extension method to automatically cache the keyset, verify tokens, and populate the `ClaimsPrincipal`.

To write your own token service that implements the OpenID Connect Discovery protocol, you will need to:

- Implement a route `/keys` that serves a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JsonWebKeySet` object derived from your pfx certificates.

  ```cs
  JsonWebKeySet GetJwksFromCertificates(IEnumerable<X509Certificate2> certificates)
  {
      var jwks = new JsonWebKeySet();

      foreach (var certificate in certificates)
      {
          var rsaParameters = ((RSA)certificate.PublicKey.Key).ExportParameters(false);

          var jwk = new JsonWebKey
          {
              // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517#section-4
              Kty = certificate.PublicKey.Key.KeyExchangeAlgorithm,
              Use = "sig",
              Kid = certificate.Thumbprint,
              X5t = certificate.Thumbprint,

              // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517#appendix-B
              N = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.Modulus),
              E = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParameters.Exponent),
          };

          jwks.Keys.Add(jwk);
      }

       return jwks;
  }
  ```
- Implement a route `/not-yet-implemented` that returns `501 Not Implemented`.
- Implement a route `/.well-known/openid-configuration` that serves a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration` object.

  ```cs
  OpenIdConnectConfiguration GetOpenIdConnectConfiguration(string issuer) {
      var configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
      {
          Issuer = issuer,
          TokenEndpoint = issuer + "/token",
          AuthorizationEndpoint = issuer + "/not-yet-implemented",
          JwksUri = issuer + "/keys",
      };
      configuration.GrantTypesSupported.Add(grantType);
      return configuration;
  }
  ```
- Implement a route `/token` that uses your application-specific logic to authenticate the user and generate a `ClaimsIdentity`, then creates a `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken` using a `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`.

  ```cs
  JwtSecurityToken CreateJwt(
      string issuer,
      TimeSpan lifetime,
      ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity,
      X509Certificate2 signingCertificate)
  {
      var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
      {
          Issuer = issuer,
          Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(lifetime),
          NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
          Subject = claimsIdentity,
          SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(signingCertificate),
      };

      return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);
  }
  ```

I would also encourage you to implement the OAuth `client_credentials` grant flow for your `/token` route.

## Update

I published a full writeup of this: [non-paywalled link](https://medium.com/p/securing-microservices-with-assymetric-jwts-88aebb7114fd?source=email-7cbd2f0977ce--writer.postDistributed&sk=58f1fd93bd117cef49444b08b86a3ff7).

Comment: Could you please share sample code of your approach - it would be very helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: Just added list of routes and how to implement them

Answer (score 16):

The only difference between ASymmetric Signing & Symmetric Signing is the signing keys. Just construct a new ASymmetric Security Key to token validation parameters will make it.

Suppose you want to use the RSA algo. Let's use powershell to export a pair of RSA keys as below:

```bsh
$rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider -ArgumentList 2048

$rsa.ToXmlString($true) | Out-File key.private.xml
$rsa.ToXmlString($false) | Out-File key.public.xml
```

Now we'll use the two keys to sign the token.

#### A Little Patching

Since the `rsa.FromXmlString()` api is support by .NET Core, I just copy [@myloveCc's code](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874#issuecomment-323894072) to construct a `RsaParameters` in C# (this work is done by the following `ParseXmlString()` method):

```cs
public static class KeyHelper 
{
    public static RSAParameters ParseXmlString( string xml){
        RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters();

        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        if (xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Name.Equals("RSAKeyValue"))
        {
            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                switch (node.Name)
                {
                    case "Modulus": parameters.Modulus = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "Exponent": parameters.Exponent = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "P": parameters.P = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "Q": parameters.Q = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "DP": parameters.DP = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "DQ": parameters.DQ = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "InverseQ": parameters.InverseQ = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                    case "D": parameters.D = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.InnerText) ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(node.InnerText)); break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid XML RSA key.");
        }
        return parameters;
    }


    public static RsaSecurityKey BuildRsaSigningKey(string xml){ 
        var parameters = ParseXmlString(xml);
        var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        rsaProvider.ImportParameters(parameters);
        var key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaProvider);   
        return key;
    }  
}
```

Here I add a `BuildRsaSigningKey()` helper method to generate a `SecurityKey`.

#### Token Generation

Here's a demo to generate a token with RSA :

```cs
public string GenerateToken(DateTime expiry)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,          "..."),
        // ... other claims
   });

    var xml = "<RSAKeyValue> load...from..local...files...</RSAKeyValue>";
    SecurityKey key =  KeyHelper.BuildRsaSigningKey(xml); 

    var Token = new JwtSecurityToken
    (
        issuer: "test",
        audience: "test-app",
        claims: Identity.Claims,
        notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
        expires: expiry,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest)
    );
    var TokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(Token);
    return TokenString;
}
```

#### Token validation

To validate it automatically, configure the JWT Bearer authentication as below :

```cs
Services.AddAuthentication(A =>
{
    A.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    A.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(O =>
{
    var xml = "<RSAKeyValue> load...from..local...files...</RSAKeyValue>";
    var key = KeyHelper.BuildRsaSigningKey(xml);

    O.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    O.SaveToken = true;
    O.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    O.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,   
        // ... other settings
    };
});
```

If you would like to manually validate it :

```cs
public IActionResult ValidateTokenManually(string jwt)
{
    var xml = "<RSAKeyValue>... the keys ...</RSAKeyValue>";
    SecurityKey key = KeyHelper.BuildRsaSigningKey(xml);    

    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        RequireSignedTokens = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        // ... other settings
    };

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out var rawValidatedToken);
    var securityToken = (JwtSecurityToken)rawValidatedToken;
    return Ok(principal);
}
```

Comment: I need just the public key to validate the token, right?

Comment: @Genfood Yes, that's true :)